# Need count of transactional table based on other tables including zeros where there are no matches

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

I have four tables, three of which are pretty static: haul_types, dumpster_type_team (the dumpster_type_team has the many-to-many relationship between dumpster_types and teams), and users.  The fourth table, hauls, has transactional data.

```
haul_types:

id
name
```

[image: haul_types_data]

```
dumpster_type_team:

id
dumpster_type_id
team_id
```

[image: dumpster_type_team_data]

```
users:

id
first_name
last_name
is_driver
team_id
```

[image: users_data]

```
hauls:

haul_type_id
haul_status_id
set_dumpster_type_id
completed_driver_id
team_id
```

[image: hauls_data]

I would like a query that has a combination of dumpster_types, haul_types, and drivers (users) and a count of the hauls they were involved in.  In some cases, there should be a count of zero because some drivers haven't completed hauls for every haul_type / dumpster type combination.

Here's the query I have so far that seems to be behaving as if it is an inner join because the records are getting filtered to only show where there are matches:

```sql
SELECT
    c.haul_type_id,
    c.dumpster_type_id,
    c.driver_id,
    count(h.id) AS haul_count
FROM
    hauls h
    RIGHT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT
            ht.id AS haul_type_id,
            dtt.dumpster_type_id AS dumpster_type_id,
            dtt.team_id AS team_id,
            u.id AS driver_id
        FROM
            haul_types ht
            CROSS JOIN dumpster_type_team dtt
            CROSS JOIN users u
        WHERE
            u.team_id = dtt.team_id
            AND u.is_driver = TRUE) c ON c.haul_type_id = h.haul_type_id
    AND c.dumpster_type_id = h.set_dumpster_type_id
    AND c.driver_id = h.completed_driver_id
    AND c.team_id = h.team_id
WHERE
    h.team_id = 9
    AND h.haul_status_id = 3
    AND h.completed_driver_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    c.haul_type_id, c.dumpster_type_id, c.driver_id
```

When I run the subquery in isolation:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
            ht.id AS haul_type_id,
            dtt.dumpster_type_id AS dumpster_type_id,
            dtt.team_id AS team_id,
            u.id AS driver_id
        FROM
            haul_types ht
            CROSS JOIN dumpster_type_team dtt
            CROSS JOIN users u
        WHERE
            u.team_id = dtt.team_id
            AND u.is_driver = TRUE
```

I get the results I want: a row for each permutation of haul_type, dumpster_type, driver_id, and team_id.  However, when I run the entire query, I get filtered results despite the right join.

What I would like to have is the following:
If I have 4 haul_types: delivery, swap, live, pickup

and 2 dumpster_types: 10YD, 15YD

and 2 drivers: 1, 2

I would like a haul count for the combination of haul_type, dumpster_type, and driver.  If there are no hauls matching the row, show 0:

[image: expected_results]

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify your data.  I'm a bit lost on the first sentence.  In addition, your sample code has other conditions that are not mentioned at all in the question.  What do *you* mean by "pivot table"?

Comment: Sorry I made this confusing. When I say pivot table, it contains a many-to-many relationship between a team and a dumpster type. dumpster_type_team has: dumpster_type_id and team_id.  I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *description* of the question and the query seem to have little to do with each other.  I don't know what a "pivot table" is supposed to be.

> I would like a query that has a combination of dumpster_types, haul_types, and drivers (users) and a count of the hauls they were involved in.

This sounds like a `cross join` to generate the rows and then a `left join`/`group by` to calculate the results:

```
select d.dumpster_id, ht.haul_type_id, d.driver_id, count(h.driver_id)
from dumpster_types d cross join
     haul_types ht cross join
     drivers d left join
     hauls h
     on h.dumpster_id = d.dumpster_id and
        h.haul_type_id = ht.haul_type_id and
        h.driver_id = d.driver_id
group by d.dumpster_id, ht.haul_type_id, d.driver_id;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have a fourth table named hauls that I want to get the count of ids from.  I'll update my original post for clarity.

Comment: @BrianKidd . . . This references four tables.

Answer (score 0):

Running the query @GordonLinoff provided, exposed the issue I was facing - when applying a where clause on the top level query, the results were getting filtered to only matches.  I moved the where clause to individual subqueries and now I am getting all expected results.

Not sure if this is the most efficient way to write it but it yields the correct results:

```sql
SELECT
    d.dumpster_type_id,
    ht.id AS haul_type_id,
    u.id AS driver_id,
    count(h.id) AS haul_count
FROM (
    SELECT
        dumpster_type_id,
        team_id
    FROM
        dumpster_type_team
    WHERE
        team_id = 9) d
    CROSS JOIN haul_types ht
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT
            users.id
        FROM
            users
        WHERE
            users.is_driver = TRUE
            AND users.team_id = 9) u
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            id, set_dumpster_type_id, haul_type_id, completed_driver_id, team_id
        FROM
            hauls
        WHERE
            haul_status_id = 3
            AND team_id = 9) h ON h.set_dumpster_type_id = d.dumpster_type_id
    AND h.haul_type_id = ht.id
    AND h.completed_driver_id = u.id
    AND h.team_id = d.team_id
GROUP BY
    d.dumpster_type_id,
    ht.id,
    u.id
```